# Signal Filtering with matlab

Tags: matlab

I have some values in a .txt file and I load them into Matlab using the importdata command like so:

```
A=importdata('Step_Response.txt');

t = A(1:end, 1);
y = A(1:end, 2);
```

When plotting this data I get the following plot:
[image]

How would I proceed with clearing this up so I would get something that resembles a line?

So far I have tried this:

```
b = 50;
coeff= ones(1, b)/b;
avg = filter(coeff, 1, y);
plot(t,[y avg])
```

This is the resulting plot:
[image]

Is this the correct way to do this and can I get a clearer line towards the end?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I will edit the post to add this info

Comment: You can then try to fit a curve to your avg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the function type and parameters of a noise, then you can build a specific filter. For example, I have used the sigmoidal function and the uniformly distributed of a noise.

[image]

Else, you can use the Curve Fitting Tool (in main menu: APPS  → Curve Fitting) and find a filter type that satisfies you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info! Although I can't find how to extract the fitted values to the workspace

Comment: in main menu Curve Fitting Tools: Fit → Save to Workspace